# How Do I generate table columns dynamically after ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery (1.9.1) with jQuery Mobile (1.3.0). I am having trouble with the Reflow table in JQM. When I AJAX to get my JSON data from a script to add more rows to my table, the reflow table headings are not generated after I trigger a refresh and create on the table. Here is my code:

### HTML/PHP

```
'<table data-role="table" id="itemTable" data-mode="reflow" class="ui-responsive table-stroke" style="display:table;">' .
    '<thead>' .
        '<tr>' .
            '<th data-priority="1">Location</th>' .
            '<th>Name</th>' .
            '<th data-priority="3">Barcode</th>' .
            '<th data-priority="4">Needed</th>' .
            '<th data-priority="5">Scanned</th>' .
        '</tr>' .
    '</thead>' .
    '<tbody>' .
        $tableData .
    '</tbody>' .
'</table>' .
```

### JavaScript

```
$('.getOrder, .getStoreOrder').on('vclick', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sel =   this;
    var theLink =   $(this).attr('href');
    if (activeOrder === true) {
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: {
            pa: ($(sel).hasClass('getStoreOrder') ? 'store' : '') + 'order'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
            $('#itemTable tbody').html('');
            $('#leftPanel ul li').not(':first-child').remove();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            testVar =   data;
            var i;
            for (i=0; i <= data.length -1; i++) {

                $('#itemTable tbody').append(   '' +
                    '<tr id="item' + (i+1) + '">' +
                        '<td><span>' + data[i].Location + '</span></td>' +
                        '<td><a onclick="showImageOverlay(\'' + data[i].Image + '\');">' + data[i].Name + '</a></td>' +
                        '<td>' + data[i].Barcode + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + data[i].Qty + '</td>' +
                        '<td>0</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                '');
                $('#leftPanel ul').append(  '' +
                    '<li>' +
                        '<a href="#item' + (i+1) + '" class="itemLink" onclick="changeItem(\'item' + (i+1) + '\')">' +
                            'Item ' + (i+1) +
                        '</a>' +
                    '</li>' +
                '');
            }
            $('#itemTable').trigger('refresh');
            $('#itemTable').trigger('create');
            $('#leftPanel #leftUl').listview('refresh');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#rightPanel', '.ui-page-active').panel('close');
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            //pageChange(theLink);
        }
    });
});
```

The AJAX **does** succeed and add my rows to the table how I want them to. My question is how do I trigger JQM to add the reflow column names.

I know that I can use `<b class="ui-table-cell-label">Column Name</b>` to my row appends to add the column names but I want it done dynamically so I don't have to change the jQuery when I change my HTML.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out that jQuery Mobile version 1.3.0 does not have a proper `.table('refresh')` method implemented. I solved this by upgrading to jQuery Mobile version 1.3.1 which has the proper method I needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion its preferable to do like this: `$('#tableContainer').load('revisedTable.php?json=yourJsonString');`

That way you're doing the table layout in php rather than javascript.

Comment: I'm not very fond of this solution because it will cause a lot of unneeded overhead as opposed to just getting JSON from the ajax and have javascript add the html. I'm also editing a panel so loading a new table is out.

Comment: @Mic1780 ok, in your case this may not be the best solution, but I wouldn't say that some html tags is a lot of overhead when compared to a json string, also it would be quicker on slower client machines rather than rending the html using javascript

Comment: You are saying to send an entire table including tag styles, classes, data, etc. via ajax when I have the table layout and events already bound. Just sounds counter-productive. But I do thank you for your input =)